# How to add a short slash (line segment) on one of the \leftrightarrows?

Tags: arrows

I want to know how to get two paralleled reverse single arrows between proposition A and B, and one of the arrows with a short slash, which means that A can deduces B but B cannot deduce A. Shortly, how to add a short slash (line segment) on one of the `\leftrightarrows`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

Proposition A$\leftrightarrows$Proposition B

I want to add a slash (line segment) on the leftarrow, 
it means that A can deduce to B but B cannot deduce to A.

\end{document}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add a minimal working example (MWE) showing your current code.

Comment: \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
 
Proposition A$\leftrightarrows$Proposition B

I want to add a slash (line segment) on the leftarrow, it means that A can deduce to B but B cannot deduce to A.

\end{document}

Comment: You can look at the package `centernot`

Comment: Can you modify my code above to help me achieve this effect? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possibility combining `\nleftarrow` from `amssymb` with the old style `\rightarrow` provided by `old-arrows`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[old]{old-arrows}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\notleftyesrightarrow}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\notleft@yesrightarrow\relax}}
\newcommand{\notleft@yesrightarrow}[2]{%
   \vcenter{%
      \m@th
      \offinterlineskip
      \hbox{$#1\nleftarrow$}
      \hbox{$#1\varrightarrow$}
   }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$A \notleftyesrightarrow B \leftrightarrows C$
$\scriptstyle A \notleftyesrightarrow B \leftrightarrows C$
$\scriptscriptstyle A \notleftyesrightarrow B \leftrightarrows C$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Loading the package `old-arrows` with the option `old` does not replace the standard arrows but rather provides the onld-style ones with `var` prepended to the name (here `\varrightarrow`).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{centernot}

\begin{document}
\[
    A \leftrightarrow
    \begin{array}{c}
        \rightarrow\\[-4pt]
        \centernot{\leftarrow}
    \end{array}
    B
\]
\end{document}
```

Use the `centernot` package for the slash and an `array` environment to have one arrow above the other, decrease the vertical spacing by `4pt` using `\\[-4pt]` instead of just `\\`